# D7: Importing XML via Feeds with multifield multilingual attachments

Tags: xml, drupal-7, multilingual, feed

we have xml that contains multifield and multilingual subdata such as events and attachments.

Top level simplistic description would be that we have items: Each item in xml can contain several "subitems" such as events and attachments. Attachments for example have: name, filename, description, date, state. First three fields would be multilingual.

Events have: Name, date, link, description, state. First two can be multilingual.

What would be the best way to import such xml? It seems that all possibly suitable contrib modules are alpha / dev (Feeds entity processor, field collection feeds).

Any advices would be appreciated. My colleague tried already with the above and failed (Multilinguality with field translation).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [Feeds Tamper](http://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) module? The "Explode" plug-in can capture multiple values from a list, and some of its text filters might help with your multilingual requirements.